# No component factory found for DialogDataExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am new on Angular. I am integrating `MatDialog` . I copied code from Angular official documentation https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview. I am facing this error when i click on **Open dialog**.

Here is My **donations.component.ts**

```
import {MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: 'panda' | 'unicorn' | 'lion';
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-donations',
  templateUrl: './donations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./donations.component.css']
})
export class DonationsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

    openDialog() {
      this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog, {
        data: {
          animal: 'panda'
        }
      });
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-data-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-data-example-dialog.html',
})
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DialogDataExampleDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
}
```

Here is My **donations.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DonationsComponent } from './donations.component';
import { DialogDataExampleDialog } from './donations.component';
import { DonationsRoutingModule } from './donations-routing.module';

import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
 import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [DonationsComponent,DialogDataExampleDialog],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DonationsRoutingModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
],
exports: [DonationsComponent],
entryComponents: [DialogDataExampleDialog],
})
export class DonationsModule { }
```

Here is My **donations.component.html**

`<button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>`

Here is My **dialog-data-example-dialog.html**

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
  My favorite animal is:
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'panda'">&#10003;</span> Panda
    </li>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'unicorn'">&#10003;</span> Unicorn
    </li>
    <li>
      <span *ngIf="data.animal === 'lion'">&#10003;</span> Lion
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I will be very thankful for solve my problem.

Comment: you need to import   **MatDialogModule**  in donations.module.ts file

Comment: @moufed i already imported on app.module.ts

Comment: visit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-buk9dz

Comment: @moufed thanks for your code. Your code is working but idk where fault in my code. your dialog box not opening like documentation , its appending

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its the true problem but you don't need the @Injectable annotation on the DialogDataExampleDialog since it is already a @Component.

Perhaps try that?

Comment: Yes. I tried without @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }). Same problem. Actually i searched about my problem and they said @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }). so i placed and no changes

Comment: And you have imported Component in your component?

Answer (score 0):

Visit here [Angular material dialog sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-sample),
This is based on @moufed's code. (@moufed, thanks for yours)
I just add one line to styles.css. This will show box as you wish.

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

Anyway, In case of this, we need to check this ["dynamically load a component by type imperatively"](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).
Of course, OP's code is implement number 2,

1. A component should be "entryComponents" of AppModule (app.module.ts or main.ts)
2. A component should be "entryComponents" of your module
   --> your module should be "imports" of AppModule.

Here is donation.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DonationsComponent,DialogDataExampleDialog],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
   exportsModules
  ],
  exports: [DonationsComponent,DialogDataExampleDialog,...exportsModules],
  entryComponents: [DialogDataExampleDialog ], // Add component to entryComponents
})
export class DonationsModule { }
```

Here is app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
   BrowserModule, FormsModule ,BrowserAnimationsModule, 
   DonationsModule // Should be here your module that contains entryComponents
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If we need to use some component dynamically with [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) or something like that our component should be "entryComponents".